# Server Explorer shows both dbContext and database.mdf active

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I may have just confused the implementation of the database to my ASP.NET MVC project, but I have a separate data layer with a connection string pointed to a `.mdf` file.

I then imported the data models through the ADO.NET Entity Data Model code-first to existing database.

When I go to enable migrations, no problem.

However, now I'm trying to `Add-migration`, and I get:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending: [201504081848445_InitialCreate].

I checked my server Explorer, and noticed that I have both "DatabaseContext" and a `Database.mdf` showing up. Sorry if this is a completely elementary question, but my suspicion is that it has something to do with my connection string? I saw that when I first enable and initially create migrations, it does show up in my `DatabaseContext`. But the next day, I see "databaseContext" missing the `_migrationHistory`, and I see the error message that the explicit migrations are pending.

My connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseContext" 
         connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**EDIT 1**
Now i'm having trouble enabling and updating the database migrations. I've re-imported the data model code-first, and re-enabled migrations.

I see that now DatabaseContext contains only the table _MigrationHistory, and nothing else. My .mdf has all the tables except for _migrationHistory.

Comment: It's double vision but it should be harmless. They both point to the same database. That one of them is missing the History table is odd, double check that.

Comment: Well then i'm trying to figure out why my migrations are not saving to the database as well...

Comment: And what happens when you run Database-Update ?

Comment: it runs through and applys the explicit migration. no error messages.  NOt sure what happened here and why it's not creating the database table.

Comment: I think this is because the data access layer is pointing to the web.config connection string ... not to the data access project connection string.

Comment: for separating you data access layer in another project ... remove the connection string from that project and depend on the one provided in the MVC application.

Comment: But if i remove the connection string in the DAL project, there is no longer a connection string to perform the migrations. BTW, for now, my DAL contains the code-first data models and context as well..

Comment: @chickenricekid The connection string should be injected into your DAL.  You should use the web one only

Comment: no the migrations will work no problem

Comment: I've tried re-enabling migrations, and re-importing the data models and no luck.... hmm.

Comment: can you edit your question to reflect the db context code.

Comment: Specifying the EF version and showing the console commands might also help.

Comment: [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16497938/) seems relevant but do check the particulars.

Comment: I think i'm going to re-phrase to a new question. Thank you all for your help so far.