# Can't enable migrations for Entity Framework on VS 2017 .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I just installed VS 2017 and created a new Core project. Inside it, I added:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (1.1.0)
- Microsoft.NETCore.App (1.1.0)

I also created a folder called Models with a class in it. Then, I went to the Package Manager Console and executed *enable-migrations* so that VS will create the files needed for me. However, instead of the needed files, I got the following error.

> The term 'enable-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
>   path is correct and try again.

What am I supposed to do here?

I seem to be out of luck googling. It's a very unusual combination (Core VS17 and EF) so there's virtually no info on the subject. Some guides talk about editing package.json by hand which is kind of hard because VS 2017 seems to upgrade the Core so that *dotnet restore* doesn't look for it but rather for a *xxx.csproj*.

In summary, I'm confused and quite uncertain how to bite the problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

EF Core does not have `Enable-Migrations` command anymore. Migrations are enabled "by default". Add new migration with `Add-Migration`.

Documentation about package manager commands [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell)

Comment: Seriously? Well, I guess it's a good thing that it's by default now. But how I am supposed to get the config files? I'm lazy and don't want to google every time or look up old projects. I prefer the IDE to do my job for me, hehe.

Comment: Sorry, I see I was unclear. In the link you've provided (hence +1), there's something mentioned about *Scaffold-DbContext*. However, executing that command leads to the same error message (except the *Enable-Migrations* becomes *Scaffold-DbContext*, instead). What about that?

Comment: Do you have `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package installed? ("Installation" section on top of that page)

Comment: I forgot to accept. You should've poked me, hehe. Thanks.

Comment: Running 'Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' in the NuGet Package Manager Shell worked for me (following the instructions in the link provided by Dmitry).

Answer (score 3):

I just installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`, then I tried to execute `enable-migrations` then I got the following message in VS2017:

```
Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked the question so it's possible that some things have changed. What version of the framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Visual Studio 2017 and a imported project from VS 2015, EF Migrations was no longer working.

After reading through the documentation on GitHub:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7031

I installed through Nuget this package:

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"

It caused a cascade effect of multiple downloads/installs.
After the install, and restarting VS 2017, Everything is now back to normal.

Two days later, with another Visual Studio 2015 project, I had the same issue, and resolved it following the above procedure, but then I got this new error:

"Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible."

I resolved this error by upgrading the project Framework to the latest ".NET Framework 4.6.2" (Scary.... but it worked without any further issues)

I referred to this documentation on GitHub:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11100

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned before, enable migrations is obsolete and is turned on anyway, and you can use the Add-Migration InitialCreate.

I'll add that you do **NOT** need to add more packages to the project, as it will already reference the necessary assemblies in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage.

You can also use your console (cmd/shell depending on your OS) instead of the PM power shell console. To do so, you need to add a reference to the dotnet tool: edit your project file (right click it and select 'edit .csproj' - and add the following reference in an ItemGroup:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0"></DotNetCliToolReference>
```

and then in the console type `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

[Add Migration in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/)

[.NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x)

Answer (score 1):

go to Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console

write

```
install-package EntityFramework
```

then

```
enable-migrations
```

this command runs for whole lifetime of a project means you have to write it only once in a project
however if we change model or add another class or whatever change we can use this command

```
add-migration migrationNameTest
```

'migrationNameTest' is a name of migration which you want to assign to it
however to run the migration 
go to package manager and run

```
update-database
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

1. Right click on the Project, then click on the option: Manage NuGet
   Package; in Browse, look for the EntityFramework add-on, install it,
   then restart Visual Studio.
2. Create a MyDbContext class that inherits from DbContext.
3. In Tools> NuGet Package Manager> Package Manager Console
4. Enable-Migrations
5. add-migration InitialModel

Comment: Add some formatting to your answer, it will look awesome[

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the following command in Package Manager Console.
2. Run the visual studio as an administrator.

> Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease

and my problem went resolve.