# How To Enable Migration in .net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName SampleApplication -ContextTypeName MyDbContext
```

I have given the above command but it's not working?
To Enable Migration Which Command need to Apply?

Comment: what is the error given?

Comment: its very common to have connection string problem ... check whether you have not two connection string name with same connection string in web.config

Comment: The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the sp
elling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ Enable-Migrations <<<<  -ProjectName SampleApplication -ContextTypeName MyDbContext 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: try to install entity framework again : Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease and the problem will resolve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't enable migrations for Entity Framework on VS 2017 .NET Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403824/cant-enable-migrations-for-entity-framework-on-vs-2017-net-core)

Answer (score 9):

Migrations are enabled by default in EF Core but you have to install

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

nuget package.
It looks like that package isn't installed by default with EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

With EFCore you do not need to "enable" migrations - they are always-enabled. Just add new migration with `Add-Migration`.

Documentation about package manager commands is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell)

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41403937/5292302) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplica‌​te-answer-to-several-questions)

Comment: Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.