# No context type was found in the assembly when running code first migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

While running command enable-migrations in Package Manager Console, got this error:

> No context type was found in the assembly 'Vidly'

I am using Visual Studio 2017. How to solve it?

Comment: In "Package Manager Console" window, change "Default project" to the actual project that contains your context

Comment: @haim770   
There is only one option named my project name.

Comment: Could you please post your console code how you are trying to migrate ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have set the **Default Project**, that is present at the top label with a **dropdown** in your Package Manager Console. And this project should contains your **Entity Framework context**.

You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31620624/2376652) to find where Default Project drop down located.

So finaly your code should be like this,

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyContextProjectNameHere -StartUpProjectName MyStartUpProjectNameHere -Verbose
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: what is  MyContextProjectNameHere  and MyStartUpProjectNameHere?

Comment: In place of myContextProjectNameHere, write your project name which contains the context class and write your startup project name in place of myStartUpProjectNameHere. I wrote like that because you could understand and replace the names.

Answer (score 29):

- As you are using visual studio 2017, I assume you might have used
  the higher version of Entity Framework(6.2.0).
- Entity Framework requires a context before enable-migrations.

In order to resolve the issue, please find below steps.

1. Create a class MyDBContext(you can use any name for the class) in the Models folder. Please find below code snippet.

Add this namespace **System.Data.Entity** for DbContext reference

```
using System.Data.Entity; 
    namespace Vidly.Models
    {
        public class MyDBContext:DbContext
        {
            public MyDBContext()
            {

            }
            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } // My domain models
            public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }// My domain models
        }
    }
```

2. Now open package manager console and type below command to enable
   migrations.

   **enable-migrations -contexttypename MyDBContext**
   (MyDBContext is the name of the class we created in step1)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this problem a few times and in my case I

1. uninstalled EntityFramework NuGet package and
2. installed **EntityFrameworkCore** NuGet package, entityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver.design and entityframeworkcore.tools.

That fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem and get it done my doing this

1. uninstall-package EntityFramework
2. install-package EntityFramework
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database
   (**Refer this link and add the "using System.Data.Entity;" to your
   model classes and follow the link you will get to know**)

Comment: This question is asked more than 5 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer