# How to enable entity framework in a project in visual studio 2013 C# mvc project?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to enable entity framework in visual studio 2013. My project is a c# mvc project which is newly created. I have installed entity framework using package manager. Now when I am trying to enable the entity framework, I am getting this error

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'MVCWebApplication'.
PM>
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF 5 Enable-Migrations : No context type was found in the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497938/ef-5-enable-migrations-no-context-type-was-found-in-the-assembly)

Comment: Did you create or reverse engineer a context? If it is in a separate project you need to select it in the console or [provide parameters](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/) telling where it is.

Comment: @AndyG before creating this post I have tried that solution you mentioned but it didn't solve my problem. So i have posted this question.

Comment: @SteveGreene I have selected the correct project name from the dropdown list. But still the same problem, please help me solve this if you can.

Comment: So you have created a context that inherits from DbContext? You don't "enable the entity framework" - you enable migrations after you have created your context and models.

Comment: @SteveGreene your suggestion has solved my problem, you can put this as a answer and I will accept this so that next time other user will find this as a solution. Thank you !

Comment: Not sure we really solved anything. Just a nudge in the right direction :)

Comment: Create a class that inherits DbContext. Example: `public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
    {
    }
}`. Also this question is a duplicate of: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497938/ef-5-enable-migrations-no-context-type-was-found-in-the-assembly"