# Enable Migrations does not work in Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget-package

I installed EF in my soluton:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease
```

After that, I am trying to execute enable migration command, but it does not work:

```
PM> enable-migrations
```

Error:

```
No context type was found in the assembly 'MyProjectName'.
```

Comment: You should add a context class to your project. Something like `public class MyContext : DbContext`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF 5 Enable-Migrations : No context type was found in the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497938/ef-5-enable-migrations-no-context-type-was-found-in-the-assembly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the target project (that has the `DbContext` derived class) from the drop down menu **Default Project**, or alternatively:

> `PM> enable-migrations -Project <MyProjectName>`

Answer (score 0):

try this command may help.

> EntityFrameworkCore\enable-migrations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31254437)