# Cannot create default database using enable-migrations without context class derived from DbContext class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

PM> enable-migrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'Memberships'.

In tutorials tutors are generating enabling migration without adding single class in model. But when i try i cant do so.

my connection string in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MembershipsDatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=MembershipsDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: can yuou add the links of the tutorials you're talking about?

Comment: updated my question with code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF 5 Enable-Migrations : No context type was found in the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497938/ef-5-enable-migrations-no-context-type-was-found-in-the-assembly)

Comment: Set the default project which has migration as Default Project in Package Manager console. and set your project as start up project which has startup.cs or the entry point.

Comment: and make sure that you have created a similar class. public class `MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext()
        {
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating Project changing authentication to Individual User Authentication has worked.