# Unable to add migration on Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

When trying to add a migration `add-migration "Inicial" -Verbose` , this error message appears:
`No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'DevIO.UI.Site'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).`

I followed the message instruction and typed the command `Enable-Migrations`, but there was still an error
`No context type was found in the assembly 'DevIO.UI.Site'`

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF 5 Enable-Migrations : No context type was found in the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497938/ef-5-enable-migrations-no-context-type-was-found-in-the-assembly)

Comment: It still does not fix my problem. I keep getting the message:  No context type was found in the assembly 'DevIO.UI.Site'.

Comment: The error in your screenshot is different from the error in your question. In the screenshot you've put `StartUpProjectName AppModelo2` but that's the name of your solution, not a project. Your project is `DevIO.UI.Site`.

Comment: This is one of the many things I have tried.

Comment: If you look above that, you will see the error message of the one with my project name.

Comment: What version of entity framework are you trying to use? Your screenshot shows `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` but you've tagged the question as `entity-framework`, not `entity-framework-core`. For EF 6 or below, the context should be in `System.Data.Entity`, which you don't appear to be using.

Comment: You are right. I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. What does it change ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a `DbContext` class in your solution, you need to know which project it is in. You should be adding migrations in that project. If you're using the Visual Studio package manager console for this, you will need to set the Default Project to the project which contains the `DbContext` (i.e. in the dropdown at the top of package manager console).

Comment: The default project matches: DevIO.UI.Site

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is different from Entity Framework Core. You are using Entity Framework (which we know because EF Core doesn't include an `Enable-Migrations` command), but your `DbContext` is coming from the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace. If you replace `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` with `using System.Data.Entity` that should be the correct `DbContext` class for Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that if you install a NuGet packages named Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools it will solve this problem .